# Bitbucket Piplines: Upload from a sub directory to staging / production server

Tags: deployment, bitbucket

I am trying to upload my project using `bitbucket's pipeline` service and its working fine. However, I only need to upload the files from a specific sub-directory.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
Repository:
  - Appz
    - Android
    - iOS
  - Designs
    - Appz
    - Web
  - Web
    - Html
    - Laravel
```

I need to upload the files form the `Repository / Web` only (not from any other directory). But the `pipeline` service is uploading the entire repository to server.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: php:7.2

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git-ftp
            - export PROJECT_NAME=Web/
            - git-ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://domain/path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The only command which requires the modification is the `git-ftp` command. However, I also found that the `export` command doesn't have anything to do here, so I removed it and the command still worked as I require.

Here how it goes:

```
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git-ftp
- git-ftp init --syncroot Web --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://domain/path
```

The specified `--syncroot <PATH/TO/DIRECTORY>` parameter is all it takes to set the desired source location from where the `pipeline` service need to fetch and upload files.

I hope this helps.
Thank you.